# Replace old WordPress Post Content with new if NOT empty

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I would like to replace all content in my WordPress pages and posts by "Lorem Ipsum" when there is content. So pages and posts with no content, only a title and or attachment should be left alone. 
To do a simply search and replace looking for some text and replacing it I can use:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET `post_content`
= REPLACE (`post_content`,
'OriginalText',
'ReplacedText');
```

Found that on SpeckyBoy's site [here](http://speckyboy.com/2011/03/23/20-helpful-wordpress-sql-queries-snippets/).

But what about a query to replace all content in post_content inside table wp_posts by content of my choosing skipping empty cells? Something like:

```
IF NOT NULL {
 UPDATE wp_posts SET `post_content`
    'NewText';
}
```

How to add that condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = 'NewText' WHERE post_content > ''
```